# Working with nested json file visual basic

Tags: json, vb.net, windows-store-apps

i have a nested json file that i want to deserialize, i keep getting an error " Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

here is my json file

```
[
{
    "Name": "Junius",
    "LastName": "Lekgwara",
    "CellNo": [
        {
            "CellC": "072685345",
            "Voda": "0728589303"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Name": "Phuti",
    "LastName": "Gravel",
    "CellNo": [
        {
            "CellC": "08377777777",
            "Voda": "089888888888"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Name": "Donald",
    "LastName": "Gravel",
    "CellNo": [
        {
            "CellC": "0791408989",
            "Voda": "0117689009"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

here is my Person class

```
Public Class Person
Private _Name As String
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
End Property
Private _LastName As String
Public Property LastName() As String
    Get
        Return _LastName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _LastName = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property cellno As CellNo
End Class

Public Class CellNo
Public Property CellC As String
Public Property Voda As String

End Class
```

PersonList class

```
Public Class PersonList
Private _ListPerson As List(Of Person)
Public Property ListPerson() As List(Of Person)
    Get
        Return _ListPerson
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Person))
        _ListPerson = value
    End Set
End Property
Sub New()
    _ListPerson = New List(Of Person)
End Sub
End Class
```

reading json file, when this sub is called i get an error

```
 Public Async Sub LoadFromFile()
    Dim reader As String = Await GetFile()
    Dim serializer As DataContractJsonSerializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(ObservableCollection(Of Person)))
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader))
    Dim listOf As ObservableCollection(Of Person) = New ObservableCollection(Of Person)
    listOf = serializer.ReadObject(ms)
    For Each item In listOf
        list.ListPerson.Add(item)
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Name + " " + item.LastName + " " + item.cellno.CellC + " " + item.cellno.Voda) 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object, on item.cellno.CellC and item.cellno.Voda
    Next
End Sub
```

i want to be able to reference it like

```
Dim person As Person = New Person()
lblName.Text = person.Name
lblLastName.Text = person.LastName
lblCellCNo.Text= person.cellno.CellC
lblCellVodaNo.Text= person.cellno.Voda
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using CellNo as an array

```
 `"CellNo":[
             "072685345",
             "0728589303"
           ]

   For Each item In listOf
        list.ListPerson.Add(item)
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Name + " " + item.LastName)
        For Each i In item.CellNo
            Debug.WriteLine(i)
        Next
    Next
```

display

> Junius Lekgwara
>   Cell No: 072685345
>   Cell No: 0728589303
>   
> Phuti Gravel
>   Cell No: 08377777777
>   Cell No: 089888888888
>   
> Donald Gravel
>   Cell No: 0791408989
>   Cell No: 0117689009

Answer (score 1):

The JSON shown is a bit different than the class structs you want to use.  `Person` is a List or Array already in the JSON.  `CellNo` is also an array even though it appears in *that* sample to only have one class object per person.

So, you can skip your `PersonList` entirely:

```
Public Class CellNo
    Public Property CellC As String
    Public Property Voda As String
End Class

Public Class Person  
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property CellNo As List(Of CellNo)
End Class
```

Deserialize to a `List(Of Person)`:

```
Dim jstr = ... (wherever it comes from)

Dim jp As List(Of Person)
jp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Person))(jstr)
```

This is now quite usable as is without further manipulations:

```
For Each P As Person In jp
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  Cell Voda:{1}", P.Name, P.CellNo(0).Voda)
Next
```

> Junius  Cell Voda: 0728589303
>   Phuti  Cell Voda: 089888888888
>   Donald  Cell Voda: 0117689009

Optionally, you can deserialize to an array of Person, and define `Person.CellNo` as an array also.

---

`i'm not using newtonsoft`

You get the same results using NET:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim jp As List(Of Person)

jp = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Person))(jstr)
```

Comment: this one is hard to follow as i'm not using newtonsoft.

Answer (score 0):

See.. your problem is that 
the item List is not well prepared for what you want.

```
 item.cellno HAS CHILD !!!
```

and

```
 item.cellno.CellC 
 item.cellno.Voda
```

**must be iterated..**

```
 For Each item In listOf
    list.ListPerson.Add(item)
    'Debug.WriteLine(item.Name + " " + item.LastName + " " + _ 

   'you know that you have just 2 items in : CellNo, and play with that.
   For i= 0 to 1
      Item.CellNo(i) ' do something with ..
   End For

Next
```

also read this : [vb.net datatable Serialize to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648064/vb-net-datatable-serialize-to-json)